# How can I send multiple options to one variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am running a loop for an array of variables that generates three more variables.

i.e

```
for foo in ${bar[@]};
    do bar1=$(echo $foo | awk '{print$1}');
       bar2=$(echo $foo | awk '{print$2}');
       bar3=$(echo $foo | awk '{print$3}');
done
```

However when the loop is finished I need the three newly created variables to become arrays themselves that I can run for loops on as well.

i.e.

```
for foo in ${bar1[@]}
    do echo $foo
done
```

^^^^this should show multiple lines.

can anyone provide anyway to make this possible?

Comment: Post how does `bar` array looks like, and what is desired output in `bar1`,`bar2`,`bar3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
      bar1+=($(echo $foo | awk '{print$1}'))
```

i.e., `variable+=( value )`
to add a value to an array. 
Of course the code to *use* the `bar1` array has to look something like

```
for foo in "${bar1[@]}"
do
    echo "$foo"
done
```

Of course you should always quote shell variables
(e.g., `"$foo"` and `"${bar1[@]}"`) unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing.

Answer (score 0):

No need for three pipelines here; just use `read` to extract the first three fields from the string.

```
for foo in "${bar[@]}"; do
    read bar1 bar2 bar3 the_rest <<< "$foo"
done
```

`the_rest` is only necessary if there's a chance that `foo` could be something like "a b c d" and you don't want `bar3` to be set to `c d`.